# Marquee Text When Text Overflows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

well heres my problem. Lets say i have 3 div tags, all are 100pixels wide:

```
<--- DIV WIDTH --->
Text in div 1
Text in div two, it overflows
Text in div three
<--- DIV WIDTH --->
```

Now, currently i have this css for the divs:

```
width:100px;
overflow:hidden;
```

What i want to do is if the text overflows, it scrolls like a marquee so all the text can be seen if you wait a little bit. But i only want the marquee to show if the text overflows.

How would i do this?

Thx, Tony

Answer (score 8):

solving the conditional part

### JS

```
var el = $('your element');
if (el.get(0).scrollWidth > el.width()) {
    // Your marquee code here
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to use .outerWidth() and not width().

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
  $box = $('div.box');
  $box.children().each(function(){
    if ($box.width() < $(this).width()) {
      $(this).wrap('<marquee>');
    }
  )};
});
```

Would work in jQuery (I haven't checked it yet. If you have any problems with it reply). Optionally, you could set a scroll attribute in css.

Comment: marquee is [obsolete](https://caniuse.com/#search=marquee). and why come up with jQuery here, when all you do here is wrap some elements inside tags? could be done in the code, no?!

Answer (score 1):

The conditional part can be resolved easily like rennat proposed.

Is it possible for you to use jQuery? If it is, build your html compatible with [jQuery marquee plugin](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html), and just call $(element).marquee(); for the animation. It's better than the '`<marquee>`' tag since it uses only divs with proper css attributes (avoiding non-standard tags use).

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work for your problem as described (plain text in a div), but if that's just a minimal case, you can use `overflow: auto`, which will add a horizontal scrollbar if it overflows.

(Note also that marquee is a non-standard HTML tag.)