# Check to see if content overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know when my content overflows my div.  If it does, I'll be placing in a link to open the page in a new window with all of the content.

Cheers,

DalexL

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835684/marquee-text-when-text-overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this a jquery plugin for fit text to width and height:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fitText = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }, options);

        $(this).each(function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            if (options.height > 0) {
                while (elem.height() > options.height) {
                    elem.text(elem.text().substring(0, (elem.text().length - 4)) + 'YourLink');
                }
            }
            if (options.width > 0) {
                while (elem.width() > options.width) {
                    elem.text(elem.text().substring(0, (elem.text().length - 4)) + 'YourLink');
                }
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 9):

Using jQuery and [Marquee Text When Text Overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835684/marquee-text-when-text-overflows):

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.get(0).scrollHeight > $this.height()) {
        $this.after('<a href="#" target="new">Read More</a>');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eF7jf/

Comment: This answers the question, unlike the accepted the answer. Worked out-of-the-box for me.

Comment: Excellent, never thought of checking scroll height.

Comment: Perfect and clean answer

Answer (score 5):

none jQuery answer:

```
if( elements.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight )
  alert('content-overflow')//not to be confused with stackoverflow
```

Comment: Seems IE6 and IE7 sometimes give incorrect values for scrollHeight. You are warn.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a structure like this:

```
<div id="outer" style="overflow: auto">
  <div id="inner">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

then overflow happens when `inner`'s width or height exceeds that of `outer` since outer assumes the dimensions of the viewport and inner assumes a minimal width and height necessary to display all of content.

You can mark `outer` as `visibility: hidden` to cause it to layout but not display.

If content includes `position: fixed` content then that portion will not be taken into account (and on CSS 2 will not even be clipped).

Comment: Question was tagged as Javascript!

Comment: @Gerben, Could you expand, please?  The question clearly talks about HTML content in a DIV.  How is the first tag being javascript relevant?