# How to fit content into a div appropriately

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wasn't sure how to title this question and I'm really not sure how to ask it either, but here is my problem. I have a ton of data that I am getting from my PHP server and I am creating a book to hold that data. The div that holds a single page of my book is only 500px wide x 800px tall so when I serve the content to the div it overflows the div. Is it possible calculate the amount of content that will fit into a 500 x 800 px div and then separate the content being served into multiple divs that size?

Comment: While this is possible, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to save off these 'pages' into your db or just show it all in the browser at once? What do you mean by 'page' and 'book' in this context?

Comment: Nick M I want to display it to the browser all at once.

Comment: Im creating an online book, with data from a server and I need it to fit into the book as pages which will be 500x800

Comment: So what do you mean by page and book? Do you have some example HTML and CSS you could include?

Comment: I do have some HTML but it is out of the scope of my question. I just need to know how to get the appropriate amount of data to fit into the div without changing the div size or the text size. Each div will be considered a page.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to count chars or words and once you hit a certain predefined number (which you will have to experimentally figure out - which is also dependant on browsers etc) then cut it off and create a 'page', and continue until there are no chars left.

Comment: @Nick M could you give me an example of doing this in javascript and I'll Check off the question as answered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45164/discussion-between-nick-m-and-juan-gonzales)

Comment: I don't know if it suited you, But I will prefer not to truncate content based on div space but add css overflow to div like overflow-y: auto, Which add a scroll bar when content is more than div height, So div height still same but all content is readable but scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a jsfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/GKZ48/

HTML

```
<div id="long-content">very long content here ...</div>
```

Javascript looks something like this

```
var pageCount = $('#long-content').height()/800;
var contentLength = $('#long-content').text().length;
var perPageLength = Math.floor(contentLength/pageCount);
console.log(perPageLength)
//var re = new RegExp("(.{1,"+perPageLength+"})",'g'); 
//var chunks = $('#long-content').text().match(re);
var chunks = [];
for(i=0;i<=pageCount;i++){
    chunks.push($('#long-content').text().substring(i*perPageLength,i*perPageLength+perPageLength))
    console.log(i);
     console.log(perPageLength);
      console.log(pageCount);
}
console.log(chunks);
var paged = '<div class="page">'+chunks.join('</div><div class="page">')+'</div>';
$('#long-content').html(paged);
```

UPDATE: Thought this will be a very useful trick to be used in various scenarios so I have created a detailed How to tutorial in my blog here http://anilmaharjan.com.np/blog/2014/01/paging-a-long-text-into-a-specific-size-document-like-pages-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Server side; Count chars or words and once you hit a certain predefined number (which you will have to experimentally figure out - which is also dependant on browsers etc) then cut it off and create a 'page', and continue until there are no chars left.

Client Side; Set the min height of the div to whatever you want (800px) and then parse your text and take a word at a time and add it into the div. Every time you do this check to see if the div has changed height, and if so, remove the last word, and then start adding into a new page.

Either way this is not pretty and I would reconsider (if possible) how you are getting/using your data.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure the div style has

```
Height:auto;
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I guess if you knew how the content was like, you could arrange them in some way. Using javascript, you could check if the content is overflowing. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802840/check-to-see-if-content-overflows) .... Delete character by character, until there is no overflow.

Comment: This is not what he is trying to do - "500px wide x 800px".

Comment: I don't want to change the size of the div. It must remain 500px x 800px.

Comment: Sorry I jumped to the post button. Please check my new answer.