# Marquee on mouseover and overflow

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched high and low for a tutorial but I can't find one.

It is really a simple task that I see in lots of websites.
Pretty much like I have a menu, with a set width, and if my link is extra long, I want the overflow to be hidden, and when the user mouseovers the link, it will marquee the rest of the text.

It really shouldnt be this hard cuz I see it in lots of websites.

I really want to avoid using the marquee tag and go for javascript instead but my javascript is quite horrible and jquery is absolutely impossible to follow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can follow jQuery on Twitter! http://twitter.com/jquery

Comment: @PaulPRO aren't you hilarious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835684/marquee-text-when-text-overflows

Comment: @tekknolagi yea. i read that thread like a bajillion times. couldnt get it to work. not to mention jquery makes no sense.

Comment: @VinceAu jQuery makes all sorts of sense to jQuery fans :P

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/vsQFE/4/

The trick is that you will need individual container elements with `overflow:hidden` and set widths for each link, otherwise the whole container will scroll, instead of each link. In my example, I contained each `<a>` inside `<li>` tags that had set widths and `overflow:hidden`.

Then it's just a matter of hooking up the jQuery and animating correctly.

*edited*: fixed an animation bug, and made a the code a bit easier to follow

Comment: gee wizzz.. that is absolutely brilliant. despite the super-hard-to-use jquery, i will try my best to implement the code.

Comment: Lemme see if I can't make the jQuery a bit easier to understand

Comment: going with the whole difficulty to interpret jquery thing, how do you control the speed of the scroll? i find that the 2nd link scrolls slower than the 3rd link... is it meant to do that?

Comment: The 2nd link scrolls slower, because both take 3 seconds to scroll. However, the second link has less distance to travel because it's shorter. This makes it scroll slightly slower. Making both links a constant scroll speed is a little bit more complex

Comment: after hours of attempting to get it to work, I... failed. I'm doing everything right and it works on a blank .html file. but when i try to put it on my actual site (tumblr) it doesnt work. =.=' not sure why. i mouseover and nothing happens. :(

Comment: This is a great solution. What I did to make the scroll speed constant regardless of the total overflow was some simple arithmetic. Instead of using 3000 as the time, use "2000 * (scrollDistance/listItemWidth)" Seems nice and smooth regardless of how great the overflow. Change the constant to change the speed (higher is slower).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your element

```
onmouseover="this.style.overflow=''" onmouseout="this.style.overflow='hidden'
```

Did it help?